# Generate KMZ file for Google Earth from PNG with bounding lat/long coordinates?

Tags: python, png, kml, google-earth, kmz

I have a satellite image in PNG format along with the corresponding bounding latitude/longitude coordinates. I am new to this format, but wouldn't a KMZ just be a zip containing the PNG and a KML with the bounding coordinates?

How should I proceed to convert a given PNG to a KMZ file that can be viewed in Google Earth?

I would prefer python code, but any help/language would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `KMZ` file would just be a `ZIP` file with the `KML` file as `doc.kml` and any referenced image.

Example KML for an ground/image overlay:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<GroundOverlay>
    <name>25N_94E_24N_93E_JOG_1966</name>
    <Icon>
        <href>25N_94E_24N_93E_JOG_1966.jpg</href>
    </Icon>
    <LatLonBox>
        <north>25</north>
        <east>94</east>
        <south>24</south>
        <west>93</west>
    </LatLonBox>
</GroundOverlay>
</kml>
```

The above would be in a `doc.kml` file with a corresponding `25N_94E_24N_93E_JOG_1966.jpg` file, both the files being in the same `ZIP` file with the filename having an extension `kmz`:
[image: Contents of a sample KMZ file]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Turns out to be quite simple, just reverse engineered a kmz file and found the same as you explain here.

Comment: Do you know if it's in any way possible to have the kml link to the image on a remote location? Since I already have the images stored on my server, it's a waste of disk space to have the kmz store the images in parallel. Shot in the dark since this probably will screw up the kmz file... something like: `<href>../my_images/image.png</href>`

Comment: Yes, you can link to a remote file with the full hyperlink, like: `<href>http://my.site/folder/image.png</href>`.

Comment: Well, this was simpler than I thought. Thanks, Kanchu.